# zlib lz77 sliding window and max match length

Tags: compression, zlib, sliding-window, lz77

I'm trying to find two parameters (sliding window size and max match length)
in the LZ77 algorithm (source code: http://www.zlib.net/) in order to analyse different 
levels of compression. At first, I found the CHUNK value in zpipe.c to be the max match length parameter, and the sliding window to be the parameter windowBits in the function deflateInit2 in deflate.c
The problem is that the compressed files in different compression levels according
to these parameters are identical no matter the parameters are.

if someone used this source code and already recognized theses parameters in the code,
it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default zlib uses a 32K sliding window.  The maximum match length is 258.

The amount of data fed to deflate at a time (e.g. CHUNK in zpipe.c) has no bearing on the compression whatsoever.  You could feed in the data a byte at a time and you would get the same output.

Comment: Thanks for your helping. but still I have a problem. I ran zpipe with 2 parameters that I defined and a binary file (parameters are sliding window and max match length - I made a few changes in the code deflate.c etc to make it work). when I run zpipe with different values of these 2 parameters, the 2 compressed files in each running are identical, meaning that the parameters didn't change during the deflating. Can you find out what's the cause of it. Again thanks for helping

Comment: No, I can't find out what's causing it.  You can look at your data to figure it out.  The sliding window and max match length determine the maximum distance of a match and the maximum length, respectively.  If it didn't change, then that just means that it never found distances that far or matches that long in the first place.

Comment: Hi, in general, what parameters/variables in the code (constant or not) might affect the compression ratio? and where they are defined in the code? thanks in advance

Comment: Read the documentation for `deflateTune()`, which provides direct access to all of the parameters that affect compression.  You can then dive into the deflate code to see what exactly those parameters do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would be glad to get a brief explaination about the 4 parameters: good_length, max_lazy, nice_length, max_chain.

Comment: By the way, in addition to those parameters are the window size, the memory size, and the strategy.

Comment: how do they call and where are they defined in the code?

Comment: `deflateInit2()`.  If you follow that with `deflateTune()`, you have set all of the available parameters.

Comment: OK, I don't understand the meaning of the 4- parameters good_length etc and where should I call the deflateTune() function if I use zpipe.c? inside deflateInit() maybe?

Comment: `deflateTune()` is called immediately after `deflateInit()` or `deflateInit2()`.

Comment: There is no documentation of the four `deflateTune()` parameters other than in the deflate source code.  So you will need to look there.